# CString issue in 64 bit

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

I have an application which I'm trying to port it to 64 bit.Compilation was successful and finally I have my application in 64 bit. The problem I'm facing is my application crashes sporadically in 64 bit.

Look at the sample below

```
void main()
{
// some processing
fun1();
}
void fun1()
{
Cstring str=_T("This is a CString in a console application!");
// some procession which doesnt involve Cstring
}
```

So When `fun1` returns,the destructor of Cstring gets called which calls heapfree and it throws an exception and application crashes.

However when I change the contents of CString to contain less than 32 characters,it doesn't throw exception and application works as expected.

This problem is not present in 32 bit. Can you please tell me why does cstring behave differently in 64 bit.

Comment: Where is this Cstring class coming from? Is this the Microsoft CString? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Maybe you should show this "unrelated processing" anyhow; it's possible you're corrupting the heap.

Comment: Post a small, complete example program that causes the problem.

Comment: why are you inserting a string that is not used in the remaining code?

Comment: @Eelke : Yes,its a microsoft CString and im using medmake compiler

 i have removed everythng in " unrelated processing" but still same issue. 
Its actually required in remaining processing but for testing purpose, i removed all the references to that string. So basically my new fuction jus contain that Cstring